# Programatically adding menu item to a menu group

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I am working on a project where I need to programatically add a menu item to a group. For some reason though, instead, of the menu item being added to the group its being added to the root of the menu.

Below is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuSwitchStorageLocation"
        android:title="@string/switch_storage_location">
        <menu android:id="@+id/mnuStorage">
            <group android:id="@+id/mnuStorageLocationGroup" android:checkableBehavior="single" android:orderInCategory="999">
                <item android:title="Test" />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/mnuDone"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_done"
        android:title="@string/done"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I've got the test menu just to prove that the menu appears in the right place which it is. Below is my java code where I am trying to add the menu.

@Override

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    if ((this.storageLocations != null) && this.storageLocations.size() > 0)
    {

```
    //if (mnuStorage != null)
    //{

        for (int i = 0; i < this.storageLocations.size(); i++)
        {
            menu.add(R.id.mnuStorageLocationGroup, Menu.NONE, Menu.NONE, storageLocations.get(i).getStorageName());
        }
    //}
}
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
```

}

I put the order category to 999 based on another post where someone was having a similar problem but it hasn't made any difference in my scenario.